# Extending transvections/generating the symplectic group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

The context is showing that the symplectic group is generated by symplectic transvections.

At the very bottom of http://www-math.mit.edu/~dav/sympgen.pdf it is stated that any transvection on the orthogonal space to a hyperbolic plane (a plane generated by $u,v$ such that $(u,v)=1$ with respect to the bilinear form) can be extended to a transvection on the whole space with the plane contained in its fixed set.

Is there an easy way to see why this is true? If not, does anyone have a reference/solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You just define the extended transvection to map $u$ to $u$ and $v$ to $v$. In terms of matrices, all you are doing is to extend the matrix of a transvection of degree $n-2$ to one of degree $n$ by taking the diagonal sum with the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $V$ is whole space with $2n$ dimensional. Then the orthogonal space you mentioned (let it be $W$) is $2n-2$ dimensional symplectic vector space (It is very easy to check the conditions). Then take another space spanned by $v$ and $w$ such that $v$, $w$ $\in W$ and $\omega(v,w)=1$. The new space orthogonal to this space is symplectic vector space with dimensional $2n-4$. You know the rest.